# Android Studio java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity {} failed to create web view

Tags: java, android, build, android-webview, logcat

I really need help. My application has no errors in the build or as I build it in aab/apk. But when I debug the app on an emulator it keeps crashing after the splashscreen. The LogCat gives an error which I could not fix. Plz help.

[image: LogCat]

[image: AndroidManifest (1)]

I cleaned and rebuilt it many times, but it did not work at all.

Comment: Can you paste the logs as the image are unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to debug a signed bundle? try with debug

Answer (score 0):

Take the WebView again which is the latest and set the properties of the attribute height and width as match_parent. Then in the MainActivity file where the web view is initialized and declared then write the code.

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Where do I find the WebView? Is it a file or something?

Comment: No it is Not a file .It is Simple a View like Text view or Image View . Just write WebView android studio will automatically suggest